# VS 2013. Why id(Primary Key) is decrement?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with VS 2013. When I create new table at my Service-based DB and set my id as primary key with Identity Increments = 1(Is Identity: true), I have my table which I can fill with VS 2013(Table data). My Primary Key is auto-increments when I add new record.
But when I add new data source, drag on my form and debug my APP, my Primary key for new record started from -1 and decremented step by step.

Comment: It does help when you mention the actual classes involved, show the relevant code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataSet+DataAdapter stack will do that, the negative values are temporary, client-side, keys.

They should turn positive after you committed the records to the actual Db.